# Redirect example.com/index.php to example.com using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect http://example.com/index.php to http://example.com. I tried following but didn't work.

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /
```

Comment: Please be more specific than "didn't work". What happened instead? Was anything recorded in the Apache error log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flag it as explicit redirect

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301]
```