# lightspeed RewriteRule for redirect example.com/index.php/* to example.com/*

Tags: php, apache, webserver, lightspeed

i want to redirect 301 all requests has index.php after example.com to url with no index.php :
example.com/index.php/(someroute) --> example.com/(someroute)

i already try below question in stackowerflow but only work for example.com/index.php

[Redirect example.com/index.php to example.com using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242082/redirect-example-com-index-php-to-example-com-using-htaccess)

please help for this.

Comment: the rule in that link works on OLS ,  what exactly is your issue ? and what is your server env ?

Comment: @qtwrk linux server with lightspeed webserver, project is on top of Laravel

Comment: @qtwrk the rule in that link work only for " example.com/index.php -> example.com " . if we have some extra path after "example.com/index.php" like "example.com/index.php/products" it didnt work

Comment: `RewriteRule index.php\/(.*) $1 [R=301,L]`   maybe this ?

Comment: @qtwrk not work!

Comment: on my test it works ,  you can enable debug log , to see what exactly it rewrites into

Comment: @qtwrk maybe it not work on my LS version

Comment: what exactly is your edition and version ?